# Finding the distance from each array element to the nearest zero entry

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity

I wrote a program, that gets a certain array and replaces each value in the array with the distance from it to the closest zero value.
Time complexity is \$4n\$ => \$O(n)\$. (please correct me if I'm wrong, though).
But I can't figure out what's my space complexity. The task was to make it as efficient (by time and space) as possible.

```
public static void zeroDistance(int []a){
   int zeroCount=0, i=0 ,count=0, j=0;
   int firstZero, secondZero;
         //finding how many zeros there are (in the given array).
       for (int k=0; k<a.length; k++){
          if (a[k]==0)
                 zeroCount++;
       }

       //Constructing an array that represents the indexes of each zero in the given array.
   int[] arr = new int[zeroCount]; 
       for (int k=0; k<a.length; k++){
          if (a[k]==0){
                 arr[j]=k;
                 j++;
           }
       }

   for (int k=0; k<a.length; k++){
       //if there's more than one zero in the array.
      if (arr.length>1) {
          firstZero=arr[i];
          secondZero=arr[i+1];

            //Finding and setting distance to the nearest zero, between specific two zero values.
          if (k>=firstZero && k<=secondZero){
              a[k]=count;
              if (k<firstZero+((float)(secondZero-1-firstZero)/2))
                count++;
              else if (k>firstZero+((float)(secondZero-1-firstZero)/2))
                count--;

              if (k==secondZero){
                  count=1;
                  firstZero=secondZero;
                    if (i+1<arr.length-1){
                       i++;
                    }
              }
          }
              //until we encounter the first zero value:
          else if (k<firstZero)
              a[k]=firstZero-k;
              //after we've encountered the last zero value:
          else if (k>secondZero)
              a[k]=a[k-1]+1;;              
      }

      //if there's only one zero in the array.
      else{
          if (arr[i]==0)  // if zero is the first number.
             a[k]=count++;
          else{ // if zero isn't the first number.
             if( k>=arr[i] )
                 a[k]=count++;
             else 
                 a[k]=arr[i]-k ;  
          }
      }
      }

      // prints the new array.
      for (int k=0; k<a.length; k++)
          System.out.print(a[k]+",");
   }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not seem to be asking for a Code Review.

Comment: @MannyMeng I think that the code is reviewable. I've reopened the question.

Comment: @Binaryl You have an extra brace at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is completely out of order. Use consistent indentation, keep your comments indented correctly and use a consistent bracing style. Don't just arbitrarily indent things either. Don't use double semicolons. Put spaces after comment markers. Don't have trailing spaces. Space brackets consistently.

I loaded Eclipse just to format this.

---

Your space complexity is just the size of the things you declare. The largest is

```
int[] arr = new int[zeroCount];
```

so it is \$\mathcal{O}(\text{zeroCount})\$. This is worst-case \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ if all of the elements are 0.

---

Don't print values; that's an unwanted side-effect of the function. It makes it unusable from other pieces of code that don't want the array to be printed.

You should use a list for `zeroCount` with an automatic resize; pre-counting is overhead that isn't needed nor useful. Since this can actually be done during traversal of `a`, I don't think it's worth creating at all. You have far too many local variables, and this trims a lot of it down. It also brings space complexity down to \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$.

You check

```
if (arr.length > 1)
```

This splits your code into two sections; rather you should deal with `arr.length == 1` the same way as you deal with the start and end. The hardest thing is keeping track of whether you've got a next or previous value; `Optional` helps here somewhat.

#### Suggested implementation

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

// ...

public static Optional<Integer> findZeroOffsetFrom(int[] array, int start) {
    return IntStream.range(0, array.length - start)
                    .filter(i -> array[i + start] == 0)
                    .boxed().findFirst();
}

public static void zeroDistance(int[] array) {
    Optional<Integer> prev = Optional.empty();
    Optional<Integer> next = findZeroOffsetFrom(array, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (next.equals(Optional.of(0))) {
            prev = next;
            next = findZeroOffsetFrom(array, i+1).map(n -> n+1);
        }

        array[i] = Math.min(
            next.orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE),
            prev.orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        next = next.map(n -> n-1);
        prev = prev.map(n -> n+1);
    }
}
```